# Exporting SVG from Corel Draw - SVG stays distorted

Tags: inkscape, svg, corel-draw

Don't fully understand why, but some of my SVG files that I export are distorted. I am creating two fonts, and are having trouble especially with closed shapes like 8 and 0, but also with h - which is weird.

I have increased the anchor points - exported.
Decreased the anchor points - exported.
Changed 'Drawing Perception' to 1:100000 and 1:1 - exported.

Nothing seems to work. Was wondering if I should maybe try to export to EPS, and download InkScape, export EPS in InkScape to SVG? I've read that InkScape handle SVG files great.

Comment: Inkscape native file format is SVG and it supports many other file types. Before you perform a conversion, consider to export your SVG file and open it in Inkscape. That will give you another point of reference. If you can add one of your files to your post, it can be reviewed by the community and possibly determine the failure mode.

Comment: If you are using Inskcape on Windows and want to open an EPS, you will also need [to install Ghostscript](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/#how-open-eps-files-windows)

Comment: Thanks fred. I downloaded it anyway, opened the SVG file in Inkscape and there was nothing wrong with it. I've exported it from Inkscape and well...still distorted. The problem is with an online program - I am trying to create a font, and the site requires the format to be svg, but as soon as I upload the image, it gets distorted. I've contacted the owner, but apparently it is an 'exporting issue'. Tried it any other way, done struggling with SVG - don't see why it is such a vulnerable format though very popular

Comment: Thanks Billy, I have Ghostscript installed for EPS handling in CorelDraw. Decided to remove Inscape